# Google Chart Error - Data table has no columns

Tags: javascript, charts, datatable, literals

I'm pulling some data from a server and it seems correctly formatted - but I cant seem to get the google chart object to recognise the columns.

The code is generated from a large table - but even reducing the number of rows and columns to just a small test set, I keep getting the error.

data is being grabbed using jQuery and defined for the chart as follows:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Can anyone notice my error?

Thanks!

```
{
  cols: [
              {id:"2",label:"ADL",type:"string"},
              {id:"3",label:"TOT",type:"number"},
              {id:"10",label:"CON",type:"number"},
              {id:"11",label:"SLS",type:"number"}
      ],
  rows: [
           {c:[
                    {v:"[FASHION/FINE/METAL/PREVIEW-ALL][20190517-20190615]"},
                    {v:19},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           },
           {c:[
                    {v:"Intensive Landing: Fashion"},
                    {v:7},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           },
           {c:[
                    {v:"Intensive Landing: Fine"},
                    {v:1},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           },
           {c:[
                    {v:"Internet: Google"},
                    {v:1},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           },
           {c:[
                    {v:"Internet: CHAT"},
                    {v:3},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           },
           {c:[
                    {v:"Internet: Query"},
                    {v:1},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           },
           {c:[
                    {v:"Referral: Saiman"},
                    {v:1},
                    {v:0},
                    {v:0.0000}
                  ]
           }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, consider adding a jsfiddle with access to the library you're accessing. Without it we can't tell what the library expects to receive from you. Also what error are you getting?

Comment: most likely, you are not waiting for the data to be returned before trying to using it, please share the rest of the code, include the jquery...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle using your data: https://jsfiddle.net/f9sz2nmx/1

```
dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
options = { /* options */ };
chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```